# How to find mean of random process with no limits given?

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series, stationary-processes

I've got a quick question. I've been set this question:

[image: Random Processes question]

To find the mean, cov, var I guess you consider them as two separate RP's so:

$$E(Y(t)) = \int \cos(\omega t+\psi)p_1(\psi)\,d\psi  + \int \sin(\omega t+\gamma)p_1(\gamma)\,d\gamma$$

However I don't have any limits to work with so I'm unsure what I should be doing. Am I supposed to find limits from the conditions - if so, how?
Thanks.

Comment: By $\overline{\cos\psi}$ do you mean the expected value of $\cos\psi$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, thank you for mentioning that, I should have included that in my post.

Comment: by covariance, you mean autocovariance? i.e. $Cov(Y(t),Y(t-1))$?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$I will assume that by $\overline{\cos\gamma}$ you mean the expected value of $\cos\gamma$ and I will denote that by $\E(\cos\gamma)$.  Then
\begin{align}
& \E(\cos(\omega t + \psi) + \sin(\omega t + \gamma)) \\[8pt]
= {} & \cos(\omega t)\E(\cos\psi) + \sin(\omega t)\E(\sin\psi) + \sin(\omega t)\E(\cos\gamma) + \cos(\omega t)\E(\sin\gamma).
\end{align}
This holds because $\omega t$, and hence all functions of $\omega t$ are constant, i.e. not random.  If you need something like $\operatorname{cov}(Y(t),Y(s))$ you can similarly apply standard trigonometric identities.

Comment: So would you suggest using the trig ID's for variance as well as covariance? I'll give it a go, thanks for your help.